# Springboot with Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I'm implementing OAuth2 on my application using Spring Boot and Spring Security OAuth with JDBC client support.

I can generate tokens, when I make a POST request to http://localhost:8080/oauth/token I get a valid response like:

```
{
    "access_token": "359e93b2-555a-477b-9a65-e5062314fc23",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "6fd1ae31-8129-4729-a86b-e756c453a58a",
    "expires_in": 899,
    "scope": "read"
}
```

Now the strange this is, I cannot find this token anywhere in the database. If I make another request to /oauth/token I get the same token but with a lower value for `expires_in` as expected. I get to the conclusion that this token information must be stored somewhere but I can not find it.

```
01:24:41    SELECT * FROM dummy.oauth_access_token LIMIT 0, 1000    0 row(s) returned   0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

All OAuth related tables are empty except `oauth_client_details` which has the client details to generate the token.

Here's my code.

**AuthServerOAuth2Config**

```
@Configuration
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerOAuth2Config(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(appConfig.dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

**AppConfig Class**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.database.driverClassName}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }
}
```

And here's my pom.xml in case it is of any help to find why there are no tokens persisted in the database.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- Defining which version of Spring Framework we are using -->
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My question is, why are the generated tokens not being persisted to the mysql database and how can I fix it?

Comment: (1) Is there a particular reason you're declaring your own `DataSource` bean? (2) Don't specify `application.properties`--it's the default, and if you want to override it, do that at launch. (3) Are you certain your `AppConfig` is being loaded? (Put a breakpoint in your `tokenStore` method.)

Comment: (1) I'm following a tutorial and they created their own `DataSource` so did I to try to bootstrap the application. (2) If I don't specify it the `AppConfig` for some reason unknown to me is not loaded. (3) Yes, it is loaded. The breakpoint on `tokenStore` was loaded/hit - specifying `application.properties` otherwise the breakpoint is not loaded/hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security OAuth 2 uses an in-memory implementation of the token store by default, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> When creating your `AuthorizationServerTokenServices` implementation, you may want to consider using the `DefaultTokenServices` which has many strategies that can be plugged in to change the format and storage of access tokens. By default it creates tokens via random value and handles everything except for the persistence of the tokens which it delegates to a `TokenStore`. The default store is an in-memory implementation, but there are some other implementations available. Here's a description with some discussion of each of them
>
> - The default `InMemoryTokenStore` is perfectly fine for a single server (i.e. low traffic and no hot swap to a backup server in the case of failure). Most projects can start here, and maybe operate this way in development mode, to make it easy to start a server with no dependencies.

You can change the used implementation of the token store with [`AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer#tokenStore`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.html#tokenStore(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore)).

Your modified authorization server endpoint configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
         .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
         .tokenStore(appConfig.tokenStore());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, an in memory token store is configured. If you want to persist the tokens between restarts then you need to configure a persistent token store.

Please find following working example. : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jdbc